# PHP Xdebug and WSL2

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, phpstorm, xdebug

I have installed PHPStorm via snap into WSL version of Ubuntu because of [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-293604/IntelliJ-is-slow-hanging-when-working-with-WSL-filesystem#focus=Comments-27-6180537.0-0) phpstorm/wsl2 defect I cannot use the Windows version of PHPStorm as it freezes frequently. When it works Xdebug works ok with the Windows version. However, trying to use the Linux version I had no success. Could you advise what needs to be changed when running the Linux version of PHPStorm inside Windows to make xdebug work? (either by using Linux Chromium or Windows Chrome).

What should I set `xdebug.client_host`? Should I keep it as `host.docker.internal` or change it?

(verification of Linux version of PHPStorm running in WSl)
[image]

Comment: @Destroy666 `wsl hostname -i` returns `127.0.1.1` and it tried this IP that does not work. Should I use another IP address? How to get it?

Comment: I misread, try whatever IP is in  `"$(hostname).local"` since PHPStorm reports WSL2 from what I see.

Comment: See if [this post](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W-NzNtExf5C4eOu3rRQm1WlWnbW44u3ANDDA49d3FD4/edit?pli=1) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-58887/PHP-debugging-doesnt-work-under-WSL-Ubuntu-and-PHP-in-Docker-container#focus=Comments-27-4906173.0-0).

Help -> Edit custom VM options and put this in there:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

See the link for more details. Jamie Holly is a legend to posting the solution.

`xdebug.client_host` should be `host.docker.internal` as usual.